# Is there any advantage to finishing battles quickly?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

At the end of each battle in Fire Emblem: Awakening, it shows you how many turns it took you to finish the battle. Is there any advantage for completing a battle in under a certain number or moves? The fact that it shows this statistic makes me want to go quickly, but my better judgment tells me to take my time and minimize damages through the battle.

**Does the number of turns taken to finish a battle matter?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just an FYI.  So when you re-do some missions or compare to your friends, it gives you an idea how long they took, and if they did it faster.

Answer (score 1):

Like Frank said, the number of turns it takes you to complete a battle doesn't affect anything. It's just something to grade yourself on. However, the faster you complete a battle, the less enemies appear. If you take more turns, more enemies show up and you have more of a chance of losing the battle. Just take as much time as you need. If you take longer to complete a battle you may be able to obtain more items though.